# From my admin section, I cannot add new plugin and new theme (wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress,  From my admin section I dont have the add new plugin button, add new theme button and some plugin cannot be use ...  Any ideal why?

Screenshot:
https://snag.gy/j1Dwxr.jpg

Your help will be appreciated .. I cannot find a fix for this.. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you checked the files permissions?

Comment: There are entirely too many possibilities for us to help with this little information.

Comment: Yes all file permission are checked and fine ..   I never seen this issues in the past ..

Comment: @cale_b Let me know what information I should provide if something else is needed.. I disabled all plugin did not work, switch theme did not work .. ect I tried all the basic things.

Comment: You are saying that with _no plugins_ enabled, and with the 2017 theme, this problem persists?

Comment: Your user does not have permission to add plugins.  What is your user's role?

Comment: @cale_b Yes the problem persist even then.

Comment: User role: admin

Comment: wp_capabilities
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

Comment: wp_user_level
10

Comment: _all information you should have included in the original question_.  The only other possibility is that this is a multi-site installation, and your user is not the network administrator.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate but no this is not a multi site ... I will just export my content and reinstall a new wordpress ( I did already tried to overwrite all file with  a new wp)

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure you account is an administrator account

2.) Check with your hosting provider to see if they allow you to install plugins and themes, they may disable your ability to update/install plugins and themes via your wp-config.php

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: Yes I am admin,  I checked the permission in the phpmyadmin as well and they are like they should.    Its on my server so hosting is not limited ( i run many other sites on that server and no issues.

Comment: did you check your wp-config.php to see if you found the DISALLOW_FILE_MODS set to true?